# How to automatically extract information from Microsoft Forms using python-pptx package?

Tags: python, web-scraping, raspberry-pi, python-pptx, microsoft-forms

I am trying to create a program that will allow workers at a company to automatically add information to a digital noticeboard which is connected to a Raspberry Pi. They'll submit information on an online form and then a python-pptx enabled program will turn it into nicely designed PowerPoint slides.

I've managed to get a script that can enter the login information for my Microsoft forms account and print the session using:

```
import requests

print('starting')

#This URL will be the URL that your login form points to with the "action" tag.
POST_LOGIN_URL = #insert URL for microsoft forms login page with username 

#This URL is the page you actually want to pull down with requests.
REQUEST_URL = #insert URL you want in the microsoft forms page (responses)

payload = {
    'passwd’: ‘mypassowrd' 

#insert your password ('passwd' is the microsoft forms variable name)

}

with requests.Session() as session:
    post = session.post(POST_LOGIN_URL, data=payload)
    r = session.get(REQUEST_URL)
    print(type(r))
    print((r.text))
```

The types of r and of r.text are:

```
print(type(r))
<class 'requests.models.Response'>

print(r.text)
<class 'str'>
```

Where `REQUEST_URL` is the url of the results for the form (page looks like: [Microsoft Forms results page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z32X2.png)). I then want to be able to automatically **scrape** the information of all the results. This is displayed on a page like this: [results printed on microsoft forms page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXbXI.png).

My issue is then extracting the information from that url. When I print r.text, I get information from the page, but it more seems to be HTTP formatting and hashing (I can include the output of print(r.text), but is several pages long and more confusing than anything).

I'm trying to find a way to reliably copy [specific data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXbXI.png) from the microsoft forms webpage, but currently don't know a function that is able to do that. Does anyone have any experience with the python requests library? Or has anyone tried anything like this before?

Thanks,

Luke

Comment: What form is `r.text` now and what do you want to extract from it? Sounds like a parsing problem, so the form of the text is a critical aspect. Maybe you can paste in enough of it to give us the idea.

Comment: When I print the type of r and of r.text, I'm told that r is:  <class 'requests.models.Response'> and that r.text is just a string (<class 'str'>). I'm about to edit my post to put in some extra information on it!

Comment: I think I found that a better way to do all of this is by using the Microsoft Power Automate feature to save the forms data to a Sharepoint list. This (I hope) should be easy to access through the python library sharepy.